# Debugging google script for google sheet in desktop IDE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide

I am writing some google scripts code to modify a google sheet. Debugging in the online debugger is frustrating because libraries can't be debugged and stepped through using the online IDE. Is there a way to work on the code using a desktop IDE and debug it in the IDE? This seems complicated because it needs to interact with the google sheet.
I have seen a lot of tutorials to get/push the code to the google script, but not any to debug it on the desktop IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging google script library for google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943913/debugging-google-script-library-for-google-sheet)